# How to convert loop to shortest list comprehension form?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get the shortest code to obtaina list of unique parameters (in order of appearence). These parameters are to the left
of each `parameter = something`. I was able to build the below loop that works and stores in `h` the parameters

```
data = [
    'B = 3', 
    'T = 0', 
    'N = 5', 
    'V = 2', 
    'N = 1', 
    'V = 4',
    'B = 7', 
    'T = 2',
]

h = []
for d in data:
    el = d.split("=", 1)[0].strip()
    if el not in h:
        h.append(el)

>>> h
['B', 'T', 'N', 'V']
```

Then, I'd like to convert this in list comprehension and this works but I think there would be a way to write it even shorter without repeat the
part `d.split("=", 1)[0].strip()` twice.

```
h = []
[h.append(d.split("=", 1)[0].strip()) for d in data if d.split("=", 1)[0].strip() not in h ]
```

I've tried this but doesn't seem to be the correct syntax.

```
h = []
[el = d.split("=", 1)[0].strip() h.append(el) for d in data if el not in h ]
```

Comment: there is no great way to turn this into a list comprehension, because it requires looking at the contents of the list being created. List comprehensions are for *mapping/filtering* operations. They aren't just one-line for-loops

Comment: "I'm trying to get the shortest code to  ..." is almost **never** a good thing to want to do. You should want performant, readable, maintainable code. Not short code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While preserving order (and assuming you really only want the first character):

```
list(dict.fromkeys(s[0] for s in data))
```

Or to get the first set of characters before a space:

```
list(dict.fromkeys([s.split()[0] for s in data]))
```

You could also get fancy with this using map and `operator.itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter

list(dict.fromkeys(map(itemgetter(0), map(split, data))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually the parameters could have any length

Comment: That's what the second option is for

Comment: I selected your 2nd solution because it seems to be faster. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
h = list(set(s.split()[0].strip() for s in data))
print(h)
```

Prints:

```
['N', 'V', 'B', 'T']
```